# Compare master and child dataframe and extract new rows base on two column values only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes as:

Master_DF:

```
Symbol,Strike_Price,C_BidPrice,Pecentage,Margin_Req,Underlay,C_LTP,LotSize
JETAIRWAYS,110.0,1.25,26.0,105308.9,81.05,1.2,2200
JETAIRWAYS,120.0,1.0,32.0,96156.9,81.05,1.15,2200
PCJEWELLER,77.5,0.95,27.0,171217.0,56.95,1.3,6500
PCJEWELLER,80.0,0.8,29.0,161207.0,56.95,0.95,6500
PCJEWELLER,82.5,0.55,31.0,154772.0,56.95,0.95,6500
PCJEWELLER,85.0,0.6,33.0,147882.0,56.95,0.7,6500
PCJEWELLER,90.0,0.5,37.0,138977.0,56.95,0.55,6500
```

and Child_DF:

```
Symbol,Strike_Price,C_BidPrice,Pecentage,Margin_Req,Underlay,C_LTP,LotSize
JETAIRWAYS,110.0,1.25,26.0,105308.9,81.05,1.2,2200
JETAIRWAYS,150.0,1.3,22.0,44156.9,81.05,1.05,2200
PCJEWELLER,77.5,0.95,27.0,171217.0,56.95,1.3,6500
PCJEWELLER,100.0,1.8,29.0,441207.0,46.95,4.95,6500
```

I want compare child_DF with master_DF base on Column (Symbol,Strike_Price) i.e. **if the Symbol & Strike_Price are already available in master_DF then it will not be consider as new data.**

New Rows are:

```
Symbol,Strike_Price,C_BidPrice,Pecentage,Margin_Req,Underlay,C_LTP,LotSize
JETAIRWAYS,150.0,1.3,22.0,44156.9,81.05,1.05,2200
PCJEWELLER,100.0,1.8,29.0,441207.0,46.95,4.95,6500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use right [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and then [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) 'right_only', finally [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to get columns in order of child:

```
(master.merge(child,on=['Symbol','Strike_Price'],how='right',
          suffixes=('_',''),indicator=True)
    .query('_merge=="right_only"')).reindex(child.columns,axis=1)
```

---

```
       Symbol  Strike_Price  C_BidPrice  Pecentage  Margin_Req  Underlay  \
2  JETAIRWAYS         150.0         1.3       22.0     44156.9     81.05   
3  PCJEWELLER         100.0         1.8       29.0    441207.0     46.95   

   C_LTP  LotSize  
2   1.05     2200  
3   4.95     6500
```

Comment: you can also try `pd.concat([child, pd.concat([master]*2)]).drop_duplicates(["Symbol", "Strike_Price"], keep=False)` , works well too

Answer (score 0):

1. First merge both dataframe on symbol and strike_price setting indicator=True and how='right'

`result = pd.merge(master_df[['Symbol','Strike_Price']],child_df,on=['Symbol','Strike_Price'],indicator=True,how='right')`

2. Then filter right_only from _merge column to get desired result

   `result = result[result['_merge']=='right_only']`

   [Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYMRZ.png)